# Install Specific Version of Ruby with `apt-get install ruby-full ruby-dev`

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation

When I execute `apt-get install ruby-full ruby-dev` I am getting ruby 2.3. I want ruby 1.9.3.

How do I get it to install ruby 1.9.3?

I'm using Ubuntu 16.0.4 Xenial.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen the question because there's no Ruby v1.9.* shipped through Xenial's repositories as far as I can tell. A better duplicate would be [How to find and install latest Ruby version using RVM?](/q/330072/175814) whose accepted answer can be used to install any Ruby version.

Comment: instead of using `apt-get` for provisioning the ruby install I think I'll use `RVM`

Comment: use a ruby version manager, such as rbenv.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't mentioned which version of Ubuntu you are using, anyway based on the version of ruby you are getting: `2.3` I guess you are running `xenial` or something newer that of that.

If you [search](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=ruby-full&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) for the package you are looking for at [Ubuntu Packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com), you will see that your desired version `1.9.3` only exist in `trusty`; so you simply can't install or downgrade it from `2.3` to `1.9.3` because it does not exist in any of your running Ubuntu repositories.

So what you can do is installing it from a third party PPA, the closest thing to your desired version which I found is [Brightbox Ruby PPA](https://launchpad.net/~brightbox/+archive/ubuntu/ruby-ng), they have compiled `1.9.1` for all available Ubuntu versions from `lucid` to `yakkety`; They have a source package for `zesty` but they didn't compile it yet.